# Sound synchronization?

Tags: android, loops, audio

I'm newbie in programming and I'm try to do a audio app that plays audio samples, but i want to sync all of them. Like a verification loop that counts 0, 1, 2, 3. And when the user click "play/stop", the audio only start/stop if the loop is in "0".
This is one of my classes, where i set play and stop methods.

```
public class Sample {

private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;

private String name;
private AudioTrack audioTrack;
private int loopPoint;
int soundId;
private Uri uri;
private Context context;
private MediaPlayer currentPlayer;
private boolean isImported;

private boolean isLooping = false;

public Sample(String name, byte[] soundBytes) {
    this.name = name;
    loopPoint = soundBytes.length / 2;
    isImported = false;

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            soundBytes.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

    audioTrack.write(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.length);
}

public Sample(String name, File file, Context context) {
    this.name = name;
    this.context = context;
    isImported = true;

    uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void updateSample(byte[] soundBytes) {
    if (!isImported) {
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, soundBytes.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

        audioTrack.write(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.length);
    }
}

public void play(boolean isLooped) {



        isLooping = isLooped;
        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(88200);

        if (isImported) {
            if (currentPlayer != null) {
                currentPlayer.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                currentPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);

            }

            currentPlayer.setLooping(isLooped);
            currentPlayer.start();
        } else {
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.reloadStaticData();

            if (isLooped) {
                audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, loopPoint, -1);
            } else {
                audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, 0, 0);
            }

            audioTrack.play();
        }

}

public void stop() {
    try {
        if (isImported && currentPlayer != null) {
            currentPlayer.stop();
            currentPlayer.release();
            currentPlayer = null;
        } else if (!isImported && audioTrack != null) {
            audioTrack.stop();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    isLooping = false;
}

public boolean isImported() {
    return isImported;
}

public boolean isLooping() {
    return isLooping;
}

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do, and MOST importantly what are the unexpected/undesired results you are getting from the code you have listed here?

Comment: @SoundConception, the code is working, it sets the play and pause for each sample. My question is, how can i sync all samples. Like, all samples must stop or pause in the first beat of a bar, you know? Example, the Novation launchpad for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `currentPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` to get the current position of playback of the sample in milliseconds.

Say your tempo was 120 bpm. That's half a second per beat.
Now say we are in 4/4 timing, then we have 4 beats in a bar, so each bar is a total of 2 seconds long.
So to stop the playback only at the start of a bar, you would need to stop playback when the CurrentPosition is a multiple of 2000 milliseconds.

You could make the MediaPlayer stop at the right time with something like the logic below:

```
onUserPressedStop() {

    // Check if the remainder is 0 when you divide by bar length
    if ((currentPlayer.getCurrentPosition() % barLengthMillis) == 0) { 
        // We are at the start of a bar so stop and release the MediaPlayer
        stopMyMediaPlayer();}

    // Else were not at the start of a bar, so find out how much longer we need to wait
    else {
        int waitTime = currentPlayer.getCurrentPosition() % barLengthMillis;

        // Stop and release the MediaPlayer once the necessary time has elapsed
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopMyMediaPlayer();
            }
        }, waitTime);
    }
}
```